# Unexpected scoping issue in a TypeScript program

Tags: typescript, this

The code below is my first TypeScript program.

In it, I am getting an error "cannot call method push of undefined". I have included three `***` marked comment lines in line with the code below and questions about what the correct way of coding this would be.

```
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import fs = require('fs');
import should = require('should');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

interface Question {
    number: number;
    text: string;
}

interface Answers {
    ordinal: number;
    text: string;
}

class CSVFile {
    fileName: string;
    rawRecords: string[];

    constructor() {
        this.rawRecords = [];
    }

    prepareFile(name: string) {
        this.fileName = name;
        var data = fs.readFileSync(name, "utf8");
        var parser = parse();
        var record;

        parser.on('readable', function() {
            while(record = parser.read()) {

// **** this.rawRecords is back to being undefined. I think it has to do
// **** with what this means in this spot. But how is the right way to
// *** do this? And why exactly is it failing?

                this.rawRecords.push(record);
            }
        });

        parser.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("****: "+err.message);
        });

        parser.on('finish', function() {
            console.log("csv finished")
        });

        parser.write(data);
        parser.end();
    }

    recordCount(): number {
        return 0;
    }
}


var csv = new CSVFile();
csv.prepareFile("cs105spring2015.csv");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost your `this`. You can use an arrow function here instead to preserve it:

```
    parser.on('readable', () => { // <-- replaced 'function'
        while(record = parser.read()) {
            this.rawRecords.push(record);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks! By the way, how come don't I get a type error when I push an object onto rawRecords, which are defined as a string[]; ?

Comment: Because `record` is of type `any`

Comment: And I can push a value of type any onto an array that is typed for strings? I guess I don't understand that...

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Basic%20Types.md#any